# Wordpress: redirect all posts (projects) to certain page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all posts (in my theme called projects) to a certain page (also the homepage). I'm using those projects (title, thumbnail and description) only to feed into a thumbnail grid on the homepage – now they are still found by search engines and then lead to blank page.

I've tried multiple redirect plugins and with those, it seems like I need to add every single project individually (or via bulk) but this is especially annoying when new ones are created.

Hence I'm looking for a "general rule" to simply redirect all posts (projects) to the page "home".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add a simple redirect to the functions.php file:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'proj_redirect_to_home');

function proj_redirect_to_home()
{
global $post;
    if (is_single() && $post->post_type=='post')
    {
        wp_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/')));
        exit();
    }
}
```